# NullPointerException java.util.Date.getTime null object reference

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

```
Calendar datecalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    datecalendar.setTime(ConvertStringToDate(events.getDATE()));
    final int alarmYear = datecalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    final int alarmMes = datecalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    final int alarmDia = datecalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    Calendar timecalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    timecalendar.setTime(ConvertStringToTime(events.getTIME()));
    final int alarmHour = timecalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    final int alarmMinute = timecalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

I have an error in the line timecalendar.setTime();. It says that I'm attempting to invoke method long.util.date.getTime() on a null object reference,but timecalendar = Calendar.getInstance() so it's not null
I let u the code of ConvertStringtoTime

```
private Date ConvertStringToTime(String eventTime){
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("kk-mm");
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = format.parse(eventTime);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return date;
```

And this is all the notification code(The app is a calendar with event).If i comment/delete this part the error disappear so it has to be in this lines

```
Calendar datecalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    datecalendar.setTime(ConvertStringToDate(events.getDATE()));
    final int alarmYear = datecalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    final int alarmMes = datecalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    final int alarmDia = datecalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    Calendar timecalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    timecalendar.setTime(ConvertStringToTime(events.getTIME()));
    final int alarmHour = timecalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    final int alarmMinute = timecalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    holder.setAlarmbt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (alarmsIsUp(events.getDATE(),events.getEVENT(),events.getTIME())){
                holder.setAlarmbt.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_notifications_off_black_24dp);
                cancelAlarm(getRequestCode(events.getDATE(),events.getEVENT(),events.getTIME()));
                updateEvent(events.getDATE(),events.getEVENT(),events.getTIME(),"off");
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }else{
                holder.setAlarmbt.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_notifications_active_black_24dp);
                Calendar alarmCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                alarmCalendar.set(alarmYear,alarmMes,alarmDia,alarmHour,alarmMinute);
                setAlarm(alarmCalendar,events.getEVENT(),events.getTIME(),getRequestCode(events.getDATE(),events.getEVENT(),events.getTIME()));
                updateEvent(events.getDATE(),events.getEVENT(),events.getTIME(),"on");
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });
```

This all code is in the method OnBindViewHolder of my recyclerView.
The method ConvertStringToTime() is in the recycler class.

Comment: what is events here?

Comment: problem might be in events.getTIME(), it might be in wrong format or invalid date String

Comment: Events = arraylist.get(position);   It's the referenced object of my eventslist when u click in the recycler view